# How to Explore Controls whit For in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, for-loop, controls

First Excuse my English is bad!!!

I have A Web Form Where there are 120 RadioButtonList .I should monitored them

```
if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "1")
{
Response.Write("1");
}
else
{
Response.Write("0");
}
if (RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue == "1")
{
Response.Write("1");
}
else
{
Response.Write("0");
}
if (RadioButtonList3.SelectedValue == "1")
{
Response.Write("1");
}
else
{
Response.Write("0");
}
.
.
.
if (RadioButtonList120.SelectedValue == "1")
{
Response.Write("1");
}
else
{
Response.Write("0");
}
```

now i want do this whit For loop

Like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 120; i++)
{
if (RadioButtonList[i].SelectedValue == "1")//Like Array :))
{
    Response.Write("1");
}
else
{
    Response.Write("0");
}
}
```

(This example is stupid.)
How did it do ?
again Excuse my English is bad!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
string id="radiobuttonlist";
for(int i=1;i<121;i++)
{
id=id+i.ToString();
RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)Page.FindControl(id);
if(rbl.SelectedValue == 1)
{
//do something
}
else
{
//do something
}
}
```

Comment: thanks <3
but after else insert this line

    id = "RadioButtonList";

because 1+2+3+4++5+6+7+.....+121

and we should reset the string

again Excuse me for my English :|